# Android - Running a background task every 15 minutes, even when application is not running

Tags: java, android, service, repeat

I need to build a background task that runs every 10/15 minutes (doesn't really matter, either is good), even when the application is not running.

How can I accomplish this? I can't seem the wrap my head around this.

I read I could use some sort of runnable() functionality or use a background services or AlarmManager. I was thinking of a background service, since it also must be done when the application itself is not running.

What is a better way of doing this and how could I do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have have detemined the amount of time (interval) to execute a snippet of code, its better to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) because its more energy effient. If your app needs to listen to some sort of a event , then Service is what you need.

```
public static void registerAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, YOURBROADCASTRECIEVER.class);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,REQUEST_CODE, i, 0);

    // We want the alarm to go off 3 seconds from now.
    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    firstTime += 3 * 1000;//start 3 seconds after first register.

    // Schedule the alarm!
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime,
            600000, sender);//10min interval

}
```

Comment: But does this allow me to execute code even when the application itself is not running?

Comment: Yes. Alarm Manager is like, you(the app) tells the OS you wanna do somthing in X millseconds later. Then the system executes that code in the BroadcastReciever.onRecieve(), its the code that you want to execute in the background after x milliseconds.

Comment: It works, really nice, but, what about stop the service? am.cancel()? or.. thank you @wtsang02

Comment: What if I need to run the background task every 100 milliseconds?

Comment: replace '600000' into 100, that is the interval in milliseconds.

Comment: I am testing in redminote3 (android 5.1.1), the alarmmanager not working after activity die

Answer (score 2):

Alarm Manager (system service) vs  Remote Service with inner alarm implementation (separate process)?

Alarm Manager is your choice, because it already has what you need, you just have to set alarm intervals

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this via a SyncAdapter 
Here's a sample for your to look at and get inspired

[SyncAdapter sample](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/2d52182dfac91014c2975a1bb1afd99a3b14b4e9/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/syncadapter/SyncAdapter.java)

Answer (score 1):

Work manager is actually the best thing to do with periodically repeat, their default is 15 minutes which exactly like you need.
Here is an example:

```
        final PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest
                = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ApiWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
```

Where ApiWorker is just the following class:

```
public class ApiWorker extends Worker implements iOnApiRequestSuccessful {

public ApiWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    return Result.success();
}
}
```

And fill whatever work you want to be done in the doWork() function before the return with success.

Return.success() makes it inserted to the queue again so it will be repeated every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach was introduced at Google I/O 2018 - [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager).

You can find documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).