# Running android test project using cron scheduler

Tags: java, android, cron, automation, android-testing

I have created an android test project which I run using Eclipse. However, I need to run it on hourly basis and I was thinking if I could schedule this thing.

Scenario is that AUT is installed on my device. Everytime I need to run the automated test project, I connect it to my computer and '*run as Android Test*'. I don't have to create any more test cases and I know that test project do remain installed over the device.

Is there a way I could create a `cron job` over my device so that I could schedule this testing? I know how to write [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) in java and have run it through Tomcat but am new to android.

Can someone suggest some solution if exists or some workaround? Thanks.

Comment: May be you can create another application that will trigger your test application after every n minute. That application will run as a background service. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155032/android-running-a-background-task-every-15-minutes-even-when-application-is-n to understand how can it work.

Comment: Google about Android background services. They will help

Comment: I created another application(say A) with an activity and tried to launch the test application(say B) via button tap, but as i tap my application A crashes saying it cannot find the test project package.

Comment: I would use CI (Jenkins) to build and run tests instead of plain cron. There's an introduction to CI & Android presented at http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2013/11/android-continuous-integration-guides.html