# How to detect ArrayList contents not changed for some time in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a task in which the app detects `LatLng` using `LocationListener` and adds to `ArrayList` every two minutes. If the `ArrayList` size reaches six it sends the contents to SMS and clear the items of the ArrayList. It only detects the `LatLng` if the device moves only. If the mobile stops before adding six elements to `ArrayList` then the it was incomplete. I have used the following code to send SMS if the ArrayList size reaches six.

```
 private void sendLog() {

    Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,"Sending Log",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final SharedPreferences account=getSharedPreferences("admins",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String interval=account.getString("lti", "");
    int timeInterval=Integer.parseInt(interval);

    final List<String> loglist = new ArrayList<String>();
    LocationManager logManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    logManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, timeInterval*60000, 250, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude=location.getLatitude();
            double longitude=location.getLongitude();
            DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            Date date=new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM,yy");
            String time=sdf.format(date);
            final String dateLog=sdf1.format(date);

            loglist.add("!+" + dFormat.format(latitude) + ",+" + dFormat.format(longitude) + "," + time);

            if (loglist.size()==6) {
                log = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < loglist.size(); j++) {
                    log.append(loglist.get(j).toString());
                }
                SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(logPreferences.getString("admin1", ""), null,"  "+ log.toString()+"!"+dateLog+"!", null, null);
                loglist.removeAll(loglist);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    });
}
```

My problem is if the contents of the `ArrayList` not changed in next twenty minutes I have to send the incomplete `ArrayList` to SMS. Now how to detect the content of the ArrayList not changed for 20 minutes. Anyone knows please help. Thanks.

Comment: You should have to check at every 20 minute in background Thread that the Previous Content is not same as Current Content in ArrayList of Latlng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  a countdown timer and a bool value.

```
bool isUpdated = true;

countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(20*60*100, 20*60*100) {
    @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
}

    public void onFinish() {
     isUpdated = false;
   }
```

using:

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
countDownTimer.start();
```

To start and stop the timer when the array is changed.

Then test for the bool value when sending your sms.

```
if(isUpdated==true){
    // Your TODO
}
else{
    // No change.
}
```

Don't forget to reset your bool value when you reset the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **backup** kind of ArrayList variable. And compare its contents with your **ArrayList** in every 20 minutes. Use the following to compare them.

```
ArrayList commonList = CollectionUtils.retainAll(backuplist,yourlist);
if (commanList.size()==yourlist){
    //Send SMS because, this block is executed when no item is changed
}
```

And to do this in every 20 minutes, you have to use a separate thread. Use like [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class or use AlarmManager as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155032/android-running-a-background-task-every-15-minutes-even-when-application-is-n).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simplify your code by defining the following methods:

```
//your class's fields
private List<String> loglist;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable sendSmsRunnable;


/**
* Call this method to initialise the timed run (after 20 minutes)
*/
private void set20MinuteTimedRunnable() {
    sendSmsRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendSms();
        }
    };
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(sendSmsRunnable, 20 * 1000);
}

/**
* This will append location and if it reaches threshold
* (i.e size = 6), then it will call sendSms().
*/
private void appendLocation (String location) {
    logList.add(location);
    if(logList.size() == 6) {
        sendSms();
    }
}

/**
* sends SMS and removes the timed runnable
*/
private void sendSms () {
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendSmsRunnable);
    //send the sms here
}
```