# Android service runs every 10 minutes

Tags: java, android, loops, service, task

I want to make applications that read content from url every 10 minutes with application closed or not.

I'm new in Android development (I know Java, but no android SDK).

I tried the service but system kill my service when the application closed, I read have to use AlarmManager but is same, the alarm is not called if application closed.

What can I do? 
Thanks! :)

```
Edit: I only need how to task every 10 minutes
```

Comment: share some code please.

Comment: Try this example hope it will help you.. http://androidexample.com/Create_Repeating_Alarm_Start_After_Each_2_Minutes/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=93

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Running a background task every 15 minutes, even when application is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155032/android-running-a-background-task-every-15-minutes-even-when-application-is-n)

Comment: If you have a server you should schedule from there, sending push messages

Comment: You need to use Job Scheduler

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html